# Correct $.ajax Call Syntax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make this ajax call within my webpage but I constantly get this error on the console and the jquery animation is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(e){

        var dir = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['DirPath']; ?>";
    var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['login_user']; ?>";
        var datastr='DirPath='+dir+'&UserName='+user;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "RenderFiles.php",
        data: datastr,
        success: function(data){
                $("#RenderFiles").replaceWith(data);
            $("#nav > li > a").click(function () { // binding onclick
                              if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
                                    $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
                                    $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
                              } else {
                                    $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
                                    $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

                                    if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                                        $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                                        $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);

                                    }
                              }
                });
            $("#nav li div div,#drop").mouseleave(function(e) {
                    $("#nav li div div").hide();
                $("#files_menu").addClass("menuactive");
            }); 
        }
    });
});

</script>`
```

The error is: SyntaxError: syntax error

}); jquery.js:  line 2

Comment: Are you sure the jquery.js is loading correctly? If you type its url in the address bar, does it show the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that error usually results from passing an argument to a jQuery function that is not in the correct format for jQuery to correctly use it. In your particular case, the most likely candidate would be the `datastr` variable. Try outputting it to the console before  making the ajax call to see what it holds. It might not be in the right format for the `data` property.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing everything correctly. Use this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RenderFiles.php",
    data: datastr,
    success: function(data){
        $("#RenderFiles").replaceWith(data);
        $("#nav > li > a").click(function () {
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
                $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100);
                $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
            }else{
                $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
                $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
                    if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                        $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
                    }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Also make sure that `RenderFiles.php` is returning a usable format for jQuery. If you're still having problems, check the values of your js variables.

Comment: Not closing things correctly would result in the issue I described in my answer -- passing an invalid argument to a jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

It was not an issue with the call specifically. The jquery element click functions were being called twice (Also on document load). On removing the redundant call the error got removed :)